# Add review box by function at top or bottom of content

Tags: posts, filters, the-content

Filter

```
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'sandy_posts_filter' );
    function sandy_posts_filter( $content )
    {
        global $post;
        $review_box_pos =get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'repeatable_fields', true );

        if (is_array($review_box_pos)) {
            foreach ($review_box_pos as $key => $val) {


            switch ($val[nameooz]) {
                case 'top':
                    $content = sandy_reviews() . $content;
                    break;

                case 'bottom':

                //$content .= "Extra Content"  ;  Work at footer Perfect//
                $content .= sandy_reviews()  ; //shown at top only !!!
                    break;

            } //End Switch


    }

    }

    return  $content ;
    }
```

Function

```
    //////////////////// Reviews Box ///////////////////////
    function sandy_reviews() {
        $get_meta = get_post_custom($current_ID);
        $reviews = (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'repeatable_fields', true));

        $sumArray = array();
        if (is_array($reviews))
        foreach($reviews as $k => $val) {
        foreach($val as $id => $value) {
        $sumArray[$id] += $value;
        }
        }

        $Reviwes_count = count($reviews);
        $Total_Reviwes = round(($sumArray[range] / $Reviwes_count), 1);

        if (!empty($reviews)) { ?>
                <div class = "reviews-box" >
                <div class = "reviews-box-title" >
        <?php
        $get_meta = get_post_custom($current_ID);

        if (!empty($reviews))
        foreach($reviews as $val) {
        echo $val["nameoo"];
        } ?>
                </div>

    <?php
        //Get Round Number
        if (!empty($reviews))
        foreach($reviews as $key => $val) {
        if (!empty($val[range]))

        $reviews_title = $val[nameoo];
        $ranges = $val[range];
        $range1 = ($val[range] * 0.01) * (5);
        $range2 = floor(($range1 * 2) / 2);

        $Reviwes = ($range1 * 20);

    ?>
            <div class = "reviews-box-row" >
            <div class = "reviews-box-keywords" > <?php echo $val[name]; ?> </div> <div class = "reviews-box-ranges" >
            <span style = "display: block;float:left; width: 65px; height: 13px; background: url( <?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/star-rating-sprite.png) 0 0;" >
            <span style = "display: block;float:left; width: <?php echo $ranges.'%';?>; height: 13px; background: url( <?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/star-rating-sprite.png) 0 -13px;" > </span> </span> <?php
            echo "</div></div>";}
    ?>
            <div class = "reviews-box-percent" > Summary </div>
            <!-- <div class="reviews-box-ranges"><?php //echo ($val[range]*0.01)*(5);?></div> -->
            <div class = "reviews-box-ranges-percent" >
            <div class = "Total_Reviwes" > <?php echo $Total_Reviwes.""; ?> </div>
            <span style = "display: inline-block; margin:0 auto;width: 65px; height: 13px; background: url( <?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/star-rating-sprite.png) 0 0;" >
            <span style = "display: block; margin:0 auto;float:left;width: <?php echo $Total_Reviwes.'%';?>; height: 13px; background: url( <?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/star-rating-sprite.png) 0 -13px;" > </span> </span>

    <?php

        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        }
        }

    //////////////////// Reviews Box END///////////////////////
```

1- Why this function not shown at bottom of content ?

2- Why when we used this filter at top of content it's show review box at

summary of content at category page !!

Comment: How are those two pieces of code related?

Comment: We edited question, Simply we need to add filter that add function before or after content inside loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1- Why this function not shown at bottom of content ?

Your filter must return content, not `echo` content, but you call `sandy_reviews()` inside the filter callback and `sandy_reviews()` prints content when it runs. You need to rewrite that function to return content instead of `echo` it.

> 2- Why when we used this filter at top of content it's show review box
>   at
>
> summary of content at category page !!

Your category archive is using `the_content()` to display the summaries and your code does nothing to prevent that. You want something like:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'sandy_posts_filter' );
function sandy_posts_filter( $content )
{
  if (!is_single()) return $content;
  // the rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter hook should return code not echo or print.
You can use **the_content** filter

```
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );
    /**
     * Filtering The Content.
     */
    function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {

        $after = "<div>After div box</div>";
        $before = "<div>Before div box</div>";

        $content = $after . $content . $before;

        // Returns the content.
        return $content;
    }
```

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Comment: We edited question, Now can you help

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you can add a filter to `the_content` to add custom content before or after the actual content. This will give you a headstart.

```
function wepse208756_filter_the_content( $content ) {

    $customcontent = 'My Custom Content';

    if ( isset($myvar) && $myvar == 'top' ) { //Adds Before The Content

        $content = $customcontent . $content;

    } elseif ( isset($myvar) && $myvar == 'bottom' ) { //Adds After The Content

        $content = $content . $customcontent;

    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wepse208756_filter_the_content' );
```

Comment: $myvar extracted depend on foreach loop, So can we do something like this  

  foreach ( $my_box_pos as $key => $val ) {  
            if ( $val[moz] == "bottom"  || $val[moz] == "top_and_bottom" ){  
add_filter( 'the_content', 'sandy_filter_the_content' );  
/////OR   
     $content = sandy() . $content;  
  
    }

Comment: Of course you can do that.

Comment: Can you tell us how?   Or add a code here  
  Thanks